# Cant get drop 3 bar menu to have a background or close

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, menu

**Thanks Gerad for the edit. I tried the code and it closes but there's still no background and the links width still takes up the screen.**
I've made a 3 bar menu for the mobile version of my site but when its clicked on, 1, there's no background to the menu behind the text, 
2 the spacing is really bad between each page, the hyperlink for each page takes the whole width of the screen and finally, it doesn't close when clicked again (the pages go over the button anyway) or when clicked around it.

How do I get a background, shorten the spacing and the hyperlink area and make it close when clicked on or clicked randomly near it?

I'm thinking its because some current CSS might be interfering?

Here is my **CSS** code:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    #menu {
        width:1.4em;
        display: block;
        background:#ddd;
        font-size:1.35em;
        text-align: center;
    }
    #nav.js {
        display: none;
    }
    ul {
        width:100%;
    }
    li {
        width:100%;
        border-right:none;
    }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    #menu {
        display: none;
    }
}

/* NAV */
.dropbtn {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    color: black;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    color: inherit;
    text-decoration: none;
    height: 3em;
    line-height: 3em;
    padding: 0 0.5em 0 0.5em;
    outline: 0;
}

.dropbtn:hover, .dropbtn:focus {
    background-color: #ffffff;
}

.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    overflow: auto;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}

.dropdown a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

.show {display:block;}
```

**JS**

```
$("#nav").addClass("js").before('<div id="menu">&#9776;</div>');
$("#menu").click(function(){
    $("#nav").toggle();
});
$(window).resize(function(){
    if(window.innerWidth > 768) {
        $("#nav").removeAttr("style");
    }
});

/* When the user clicks on the button, 
toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content */
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

// Close the dropdown if the user clicks outside of it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {

    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav id="nav"> 
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#intro">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#one">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#two">The Ship</a></li>
        <div class="dropdown">
            <button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">Skills</button>
                <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
                    <a href="/1/skills/index.html">Skills</a>
                    <a href="/1/skills/index.html#courses">Courses</a>
                    <a href="/1/skills/index.html#apprenticeships">Apprenticeships</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <li><a href="Journey/">Journey</a></li>
            <li><a href="/1/memberships/">Join Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
            <li><a href="https://www.justgiving.com/harwich-mayflower/"> <font color="purple" size="4"><strong>Donate<strong></font></a></li>
            <br></br>
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

Comment: can you share the html as well? You only have js and css in there.

Comment: @biseibutsu sorry! Added the html

Answer (score 0):

So, you have a number of small problems, I don't know if this happened just when you copied over the code or not but here it is:

First of all ( again, sorry if you already have this but because what you copied over didn't i am going to assume this is one of the problems ) you need $(document).ready, you need to put your js code in there or else it won't run.

JS

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
  $("#nav").addClass("js").before('<div id="menu">&#9776;</div>');
  //I prefer to have the onclick like this but I haven't deleted the myfunction you have, so you can still use that giving the function name from the html
  $('.dropbtn').click(function() {
    document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");

  });
  $("#menu").click(function() {
    $("#nav").toggle();
  });
  $(window).resize(function() {
    if (window.innerWidth > 768) {
      $("#nav").removeAttr("style");
    }
  });



  // Close the dropdown if the user clicks outside of it
  window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {

      var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
      var i;
      for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
        var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
        if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
          openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
        }
      }
    }
  }


});

/* When the user clicks on the button, 
toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content */
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}
```

and in the css you do not have anything to make the background colored, so it doesn't do anything. And finally I think if you put the `width` as something else rather then `100%` to `ul`, it won't take the whole page.
CSS

```
  ul {
    width: 30%;
    background-color: aquamarine;
  }
```

Here is the [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/wfr29neb/8/) for it.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thats awesome! But, when the menu is clicked on, the 3 bars are covered by the whole menu and when you click outside of it, it doesnt close. Why's this?

Comment: Ok, is it still like that in this one, because I am not sure if I understood you correctly: [JSFIDDLE-LINK](https://jsfiddle.net/wfr29neb/10/)

Comment: Yup, still the same. Im assuming its something to do with my existing CSS interfering?

Comment: I think there are a couple of js errors as well, try to track them from the developers console on the browser

Comment: @biseilbutsu It caught one. It said "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined" the code is: $(document).ready(function() {

Comment: Are you sure you are including jquery then ?

Comment: i dont get what you mean? Sorry. Is there anymore code i could add or change to get it to work?

Comment: if it is saying $ is undefined, that means you are not including jquery. Are you sure you are adding `<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>` this tag with a correct source link. That is what i mean.

Comment: yes! thats at the bottom of the "@media screen" stuff, but its in its own <script> tag.  should I put it somewhere else?

Comment: well I don't know where your "@media screen" stuff is located on your page so all I can say is It should be in the <body> or <head> tags.

Comment: theyre in script tags. I put it there, the 3 bars are now visible. how would I move the page list closer to the 3 bars though?

Comment: you will do that with CSS, i don't know exactly so you should start googling :)